# Why 'They are us' and not 'They are we'

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I'm wondering why in the sentence "they are us" it is used the object pronoun *us* instead of the subject pronoun *we*.

A general rule is *subject + verb + object*, then I assumed the reason could be *subject pronoun + verb + object pronoun*, but the verb **to be** doesn't want any object.

Therefore why choose *us* rather than *we* ?

Comment: "Subject + verb + object" is not "a general rule". It's the way certain simple transitive sentences are formed; it is **not** general, and does not apply to most sentences. _Us_ is chosen because the objective (aka "accusative") form of a personal pronoun is the form that is used most of the time, except for subject. Subjects are nominative (_we_ in this case), but this is not a subject; never mind whether it's an object -- it's not a subject.

Comment: @JohnLawler OP is not wrong, but not for the reason they think. look up "predicate nominative"

Comment: Thank you, you've enlightened, at different levels, the darkness I was moving through. By the way I wonder why you've decided to comment rather than answer the question.

Comment: I have in fact answered as well, even before writing the comment, which was just for the previous commenter.

Comment: My apologies @Esther, my previous comment was meant to John Lawler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Either one is correct, but "They are us" is *much* more commonly used in everyday language.

There is something called a "predicate nominative," which is "the adjective (or adjective phrase) or noun (or noun phrase) that follows a linking verb to complete its meaning" [(Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/it-is-i-or-it-is-me-predicate-nominative-usage-guide), and it should take the subject form, ie "we" instead of "us", or "I" instead of "me". This has long been considered "technically correct", and generations of grammar teachers have insisted that it be used.

However, in everyday language, most people use the object form in these cases. Even though some grammar teachers may not like it, the object form is correct as well, although less formal in style, and most importantly, *the majority of people consider it the "normal" way of speaking*. You can use either one, but the "us" form here is common in most usage, and the "we" form can sound overly formal.

Comment: You nailed it. I had Italian "predicato nominale" in my mind and it works the way you described "predicate nominative".

Comment: Except that it's used in spoken Italian, whereas the nominative is not used in spoken English. And rarely in writing, for that matter. It sounds too much like grammar-school.

Comment: For a different analysis see Joseph Emonds' _[Grammatically deviant prestige constructions](http://fine.me.uk/Emonds/). Aside from the eponymous "prestige construction" (which he suggests exists only as a taught rule), English pronouns are not case-marked: the "I/he/she/we/they" form is used only in certain syntactic contexts, and the other form elsewhere.

Comment: I beg your pardon: what **OP**, **TL**, **DR** stand for?

Comment: @esa TL;DR or TLDR stands for "**T**oo **L**ong; **D**idn't **R**ead," and usually contains a short summary of a longer text. "OP" in the context of a forum or similar stands for "Original Poster" or "Original Post".